# Nude time travel in Terminator Universe

Tags: time-travel, the-terminator, the-terminator-series

Why do they travel naked in time in Terminator universe? Is it ever explained in the movies or tv serials? If they cannot carry weapons, how do the cyborgs travel with metal under their skin?

Comment: :Glad you could finally post your question.

Comment: The real question is, "Why would Skynet invent a time machine that only works on living tissue?"

Comment: The next real question is, why wouldn't they build weapons into the first two terminators the way they did with the third terminator.  It really isn't that big of a revelation...

Comment: And, of course, "Why not just grow skin over a nuke and send it back?"

Comment: @pichoscosama - have you considered accepting an answer?

Comment: @Jeff: maybe that was the only type they found that worked.

Comment: I think everyone just loves to see the physique of Arnold :)

Comment: Why send back robots, and not a genetically a modified super strain of bacteria?

Comment: @TexasTubbs Why not nuke the site from... wait, wrong movie.

Comment: This was answered in another more recent post http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43531/how-did-the-time-machine-explode

Comment: @Wikis no. I didn't like any answer.

Comment: Why not? What were you expecting?

Answer (score 78):

**Update** - this has been bugging me for a while, I finally had to write it out. It's *speculation* (not taken from the scripts), but internally consistent with at least the first two movies.

In regards to Jeff's question, "why would Skynet invent a time machine that only works on living tissue" - I'm not convinced that a) Skynet did the inventing, or that b) it only works on living tissue.

First, we don't know that Skynet really invented time travel - even *if* one of the characters said Skynet did. It's entirely probable that some (human) laboratory had worked out the basic principles, but alas, never got a chance to *publish* their exciting results, prior to most of the human race being wiped out in a nuclear Armageddon.

Second, the Temporal Transfer Field doesn't *only* work on living tissue - see the T-1000 for a counter-example. In fact, the problem that Skynet encountered, was a lack of understanding of the principle of *Chrono-topology*.

#### Chrono-topology is the principle that the energy required to activate the Temporal Transfer Field, is correlated to the number of *bundled timelines* inside the Field <sup>1</sup> . One timeline exists for every object that had a separate existence through the past.

<sup>1</sup>: Note that power requirements appear to be [1.21 Gigawatts](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088763/quotes?qt=qt0416303) per timeline, making it prohibitive to send more than a single object.

For instance, a (naked) human has one timeline, as he exists as a unitary object going back in time. This includes his hair/fingernails, which are biologically dead tissue, because they are all in the same timeline. If the field only worked on purely *living* tissue, the subject's hair (and fingernails - ouch) would need to be removed.

If the subject human puts on a pair of jeans - now there are *two* timelines inside the field, as the jeans have their own existence and path back through the past. The same for picking up a gun (and the bullets).

The T-800s, having been created and (presumably) immediately had skin grown on, have a single timeline. Likewise for the T-1000s. If they were to pick up a weapon, that would double the number of timelines in the Field.

Why the increased energy requirements? The TTF, when activated, is basically trying to **push an object out of its existing temporal path** back in time, into a *different* path. The more distinct timelines, the more energy is required for the Field. A timeline is a four-dimensional path made by a physical object, travelling forward through time. Think of a bikepath through soft dirt, where the wheels have made a trench. If you ride a bike back down the trench, it takes an effort to force the wheels *out* of the trench.

Now, it is true that Skynet *could* do a number of things to circumvent this restriction, but see the next section for an explanation of why it *doesn't*.

#### Skynet is Pac-man on steroids.

Skynet is an **AI**, and *doesn't process scenarios like a human*. It follows certain rules programmed into it, no differently from one of the ghosts in Pac-man (just slightly more complex).

Two rules in particular, [Local optimum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_optimum), and [Satisficing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisficing), prevent Skynet from doing more than the minimum planning necessary. First, when considering the sub-goal of how to send a cyborg through a time-field that *seemed* to only work on flesh-covered objects, Skynet would run through its list of available assets, realize that it already *had* flesh-covered cyborgs, and move to the next step - how to *arm* the newly-arrived Terminator.

For this second sub-goal, Skynet would realize that the Terminator could locally acquire weapons, sufficient to take out a *waitress*. Having satisfied both of its subgoals, Skynet would *stop evaluating additional options*, and carry out its plan. It has achieved a local optimum, and doesn't realize (or care) that there might be a better answer elsewhere.

Skynet, as an AI, *just isn't creative*, and doesn't seem programmed to make intuitive leaps, which would be obvious to a human. It processes trees of (known) options, and picks the ones that meet the given criteria.

Lucky for us...

Comment: +1 for a good discussion of AI and naive hill-climbing.

Comment: But every atom in a living thing came from somewhere else. For mammals they mostly come from the food we eat. The atoms in the food came from other objects, and they... etc. So every object is made up of a huge number of previous sub-objects, and so previous timelines. It sounds good for sci-fi babble though!

Comment: Never clip your nails or cut your hair or lose some skin tissue though! That'd REALLY multiply timelines. I think it's about containment though. If it's all contained within the same membrane (the android skin) it only counts as one "unit".

It also creates problems when androids get blown to bits btw.

You could say Skynet fixed up some special anti-spreadoverlargeamountoftime matrial in the skin.

And reg. not being creative, one super killer android really ought to be enough.

Comment: I'll echo what Nick said - well-written answer, but I don't find it very convincing. Human tissue isn't a single piece of matter! Part of you comes from that burger you had last week, etc, and ultimately _all_ matter comes from the Big Bang. So either this should always be a problem, or it should never be a problem. Furthermore I don't see anything here that gives movie-canonical evidence.

Comment: +1 for having a cite to a (non-peer-reviewed, and probably noncompliant with every relevant regulatory agency, including the local DMV) science experiment establishing the approximate power requirements for displacing a single timeline through the quantum displacement field.

Comment: Why is this so upvoted?   It lacks any evidenciary basis.   I realize the standards in 2011 were different, but this error of history should be corrected.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I have to disagree with the point about Skynet only searching for the local optimum. I think that any researcher who would have tried to pass off such an AI to the military would have been promptly fired.

Answer (score 72):

I suspect it was deliberately kept vague to make a good story. But from [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator.html):

> SILBERMAN: Why didn't you bring any weapons?  Something more advanced.  Don't you have ray guns? Show me a piece of future technology
>
> REESE: You go naked. Something about the field generated by a living organism.  Nothing dead will go.
>
> SILBERMAN: Okay.  Okay.  But this... cyborg...if it's metal...
>
> REESE: Surrounded by living tissue.
>
> SILBERMAN: Of course.

I think that's it for "official" explanations.

Comment: Based on that, it seems like the time machine must require the bioelectric field generated by a living body to target.  Hey!  I can BS better than some Sci-Fi writers!

Comment: why don't they cover whatever they want to transport in the living tissue as well?

Comment: @Phelios - you mean get a dog to swallow a [plasma rifle in the 40-watt range](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4380/why-would-terminator-ask-for-weapon-that-surely-only-exists-in-distant-future)?

Comment: no.. more like creating different shapes of terminators that has destructive ability probably. Just like the T-X in Terminator 3.

Comment: @Phelios - I think you've partially answered your own question, and it's partially covered by other answers here. At first Skynet thought, how hard can it be to kill one woman? (So, no weapon required.) Then (T2), OK let's send an armed Terminator. Then (T3), OK let's improve the weaponry. My guess.

Comment: I only watched the last 2 movies of the terminators, so not really quite sure what is happening haha:) and I was reading the wiki about T-X and the T-1000, they are not covered by living tissue, but liquid metal. Right? so probably they upgraded their teleport machine

Comment: This is correct. Terminators had to be sheathed in skin in order to travel back in time.

Comment: @Asmor - I know its correct but how do we explain the T2000?

Comment: You mean the T-1000? That's a good question. I don't think it was ever directly addressed, but I could see two explanations. 1: The nanites composing its body may have been able to form into actual skin or 2: the t-1000 was sent back in time as a blob in a sheath of flesh, and then it immediately broke out of it.

Comment: @Asmor - for explanation 2, they could then have taken back any technology, e.g. guns.

Comment: @WikisAtArea51 Indeed. I'd just chalk that up to a plot hole. E.g. There's no reason a gun couldn't just be encased within a terminator's exoskeleton, like Optimus Prime carrying the Matrix of Leadership in Transformers.

Comment: For that matter, Reese could have brought back any advanced technology small enough to swallow.  (Plot hole here, as it's out of character for future-Connor not to have thought of that.)

Comment: They could have sent back a big enough gun covered by a skin of a recently skinned animal...

Comment: @vsz: the script (quoted above) says the field requires a *living* organism.

Comment: @Asmor It actually was. T-X brought the guns with her in Terminator 3. The previous terminators didn't have this tech, so they went unarmed. T-1000 was only partially so, though, because he always had stabbing weapons with him, just not the guns.

Comment: @Tynam: I just saw _Genesys_, and had a similar thought.  There are ways to conceal small items (or small parts of larger items) inside the human body, and retrieve them later.  Harry Houdini was purportedly able to conceal lockpicks in his stomach and regurgitate them on demand; spycraft is known for concealing items... elsewhere.  Presumably Kyle Reese could have carried small weapons, or instructions for assembling advanced weapons with less-advanced materials in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 14):

I don't recall very clearly, but I think this issue was raised in the first movie. The guy sent back in time is being questioned about the terminator and he says that the terminator is surrounded by living tissue because bare metal can't be transported back, only living material can.

Comment: It was explained in the first movie...  It was a scientifically horrible expliation why a complex machine like a gun could not be brought back, but a terminator could because of the living tissue surrounding it.  I was like so feed the gun to a catfish and send them all back...

Comment: They only had these Androids on hand! All catfish died! Maybe swallow a teensy little railgunny though. Nah, no need, you're a terminator robot!

Comment: The thing is, only Kyle Reese would need the advanced weaponry. The Terminator is chasing after a fragile human and (correctly) Skynet reasoned he could easily acquire a gun which could kill Sarah fairly effectively. It was Reese who needed the advanced weapons in order to fight the bulletproof terminator, but of course the humans probably don't have access to the "put a machine inside skin" technology.

Answer (score 14):

In some of the comic books, Terminators bring weapons with them back in time by storing them inside of dead humans.

Comment: In the one I read, it a live human. Not for long though; nasty way to go.

Comment: Yeah, should definitely be live humans.

Comment: Nothing dead will go!

Answer (score 7):

The general argument posed in all such scenarios is that something about clothing is fundamentally difficult to transport at the same time as a person. One connected entity is easier to transport than multiple objects which are closely bound. It could mistake the distance, and thereby force clothing to stick to a person, for instance.

The [Terminator wiki](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/The_Terminator_%28film%29) states:

> The Terminator arrives nude because of the time machine being powered
>   by organic matter, so that clothes, weapons, etc. can't be sent back.

Comment: What about the metal under their skins?

Comment: @pichoscosama: It seems likely that they must have created a metal specifically for the purpose of time traveling.

Comment: @pearsonartphoto: Why not make guns out of that metal?

Comment: @Dampe - because then they couldn't have Arnie asking for Uzi 9mm

Comment: @pichoscosama: It's not a special metal (just the normal terminator endoskeleton), it's the flesh grown over it that lets them travel in time.  Apparantly, T-1000 series robots can perfectly mimic that flesh, through SCIENCE!

Comment: @Jeff [_That can't be the case because the fact still remains it's not live, and only live things can move through time. The novelization and T2 extreme DVD text commentary explains that T-1000 was wrapped inside a flesh cocoon, that's why T-1000's arrival was done off screen._](http://www.jamescamerononline.com/T2FAQ.htm)