# Do all terminators have to travel back in time naked?

Tags: time-travel, the-terminator-series, the-terminator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nude time travel in Terminator Universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4752/nude-time-travel-in-terminator-universe)

In the first Terminator film, the T-800 travels back in time completely naked. See [Nude time travel in Terminator Universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4752/nude-time-travel-in-terminator-universe) for the reason behind this requirement. Is this a requirement for all terminator robots, or were the robots eventually able to advance technology far enough such that inanimate objects could travel through as well? Are there any instances throughout the *Terminator* franchise where inanimate objects not surrounded with living tissue were transported back?

Comment: I don't agree with the proposed duplicate. [Nude time travel in Terminator Universe](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4752) is about explaining why; this question is about whether this is systematic. I've edited the question to make the difference more apparent.

Comment: That question and accepted answer there clearly say what's in the canon. This question could be said subset of that question, then. Hence, duplicate...

Comment: @SachinShekhar, I wish it *was* an accepted answer, but so it goes... :) I can't complain, at least it got a lot of votes (and a nice bounty, thanks to @e-sushi).