# Time travel to the same time and same space

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

In terminator-2 movie, the time-landing of terminator destroys a sphere-like volume of surroundings (at least heats/ionizes to some degree). Why didn't the non-liquid terminator arrive in just the exact place and exact time as the other terminator? They can travel in time/space onto a target ground without serious space error (can they?).

And they didn't even have to send a terminator. They could just send some explosive through.

Was it some "uncertainity principle" that makes it impossible to have a very small error?

Comment: Re: Why they can't send back weapons: [Nude time travel in Terminator Universe](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4752/nude-time-travel-in-terminator-universe)

Comment: Because the second Terminator hadn't been sent back yet, despite arriving slightly earlier. And yes, that makes no sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imagine you're SkyNet. You want to kill young John Conner. You could send a bomb to his city, but there's a large probability (say 10%) that he will not be within the blast radius. Better to send a T-1000 to track him down and kill him. And give it the advantage of stealth; have it appear in a sparsely populated part of the city *at night*.

Now be the adult John Conner. You want to send the T-800 back to defend your young self, but you know that it cannot defeat the T-1000 in a straight fight. You can give it information which the T-1000 will not have, but you must let it operate covertly long enough to clothe and arm itself before the confrontation, which means sending it to a slightly different place, *at night*.

**EDIT:**

Now that I think about it, John Conner probably never knew where the T-1000 arrived, so he couldn't send the T-800 there even if he wanted to.